# form doesn't allow editing

Tags: django, django-forms, arguments, editing, keyword

I have a following form:

```
class PlayForwardPageForm(forms.ModelForm):        
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(PlayForwardPageForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    class Meta:
        model = PlayForwardPage
        exclude = ( 'id',)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):     
        post = super(PlayForwardPageForm, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
        post.save()
```

and view that shows it :

```
object = PlayForwardPage.objects.all()[0]
form = PlayForwardPageForm(instance=object)

if request.method == "POST":
    form = PlayForwardPage(data=request.POST, instance=object)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('manage_playforward',))
else:
    form = PlayForwardPageForm(instance=object)
```

When loading page everything works fine. But when I try to save the form with changed data I get:

`'data' is an invalid keyword argument for this function`

Can anyone see any reason or this behavior ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: `PlayForwardPage` is a model not a `ModelForm`.

Here's the corrected code, with some extra style comments.

```
# Don't shadow built-ins (in your case "object")
play_forward_page = PlayForwardPage.objects.all()[0]
# Don't need this form declaration.  It'll always be declared below. form = PlayForwardPageForm(instance=object)

if request.method == "POST":
    # Should be a the form, not the model.
    form = PlayForwardPageForm(data=request.POST, instance=play_forward_page)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('manage_playforward',))
else:
    form = PlayForwardPageForm(instance=play_forward_page)
```

Also, you're doing some unnecessary things in your PlayForwardPageForm:

```
class PlayForwardPageForm(forms.ModelForm):        

# This __init__ method doesn't do anything, so it's not needed.
#    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
#        super(PlayForwardPageForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    class Meta:
        model = PlayForwardPage
        exclude = ( 'id',)

#  You don't need this since you're not doing anything special.  And in this case, saving the post twice.
#    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):     
#        post = super(PlayForwardPageForm, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
#        post.save()
```